# Weird iOS Keychain access group behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, keychain

Recently we added Apple Pay support to our project and it caused some problems accessing data stored in iOS KeyChain. Basically we couldn't access "old" data that was stored before adding the entitlements file.
In the entitlement file we only got the `com.apple.developer.in-app-payments` value (we don't used shared keychain groups).

I manually dumped the keychain data from the simulator and noticed that the "old" data access group (agrp) is set to test and the new data (I wrote a value to the same "default" keystore to understand the difference) agrp is set to the bundle identifier.

Anyone knows what's the "test" agrp and why the old data gets that access group?
More importantly - is there any way to access that old data again?

Comment: Are you only seeing this on the simulator, or on a device as well?

Comment: @lxt indeed it seems to be happening only in the simulator, real device gets the correct agrp values.

Comment: I have seen same issue after adding an app group to project. Not sure if this is a bug in simulator. Real devices work just fine. @NimrodGutman did you get any answer on this issue?